# How to prevent from automatic changes in environment variable in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I used environment variable in my dotnet project, but every 1 hour environment changed to the initial environment. but I want to keep the second one. How to prevent from automatic changes in environment variable. this happen in the production mode. when I release the app
used...

> Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable()
> Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()

Comment: Environment variables don't magically change on their own.

Comment: Environment variables have nothing to do with Entity Framework.

Comment: I hope so, but mine got changed... it has second changes from yesterday

Comment: Agree with the above. There is probably another application or a group policy that is changing the value of the variable. You'd need to find out what was causing the change.

Comment: I used Shared Host. it may be this?

Comment: It's far more likely that your process was restarted and so inherits the *default* environment settings each time rather than something else mysteriously changing the value. You need to understand your hosting environment (of which we know nothing) to find out if there are ways to change the defaults. If not, it seems environment variables are the wrong tool for whatever job you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I used shared hosting, I have access to plesk control panel in order to upload my project. what can I replace with environment?